# Quad-Buffered Stereo under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 3d

Does anyone know how to get Quad-Buffered Stereo working under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

I have a monitor that is supporting it, and also a [NVIDIA Quadro P4000](http://www.pny.com/nvidia-quadro-p4000) card. I tried all kinds of variations in `Xorg`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf so the 'screen' section looks like this;

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ XL2420TX"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 140.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 120.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Videocard0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro K420"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Default Screen"
    Device         "Videocard0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "10"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: 1920x1080_120 +0+0, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select
 +1920+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection